# Rav Avigdor Miller on doing teshuva on ones own accord

Tags: sources-mekorot

Rav Avigdor Miller, in one of his lectures, explains that the words

> [ברעב זנתנו ובשבע כלכלתנו](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_The_Order_of_Prayer.1.5)

in the prayer of Nishmat means to say that one should turn his faith to God before God forces him to do so.

Does anyone know of where this is written, or where Rav Miller took this idea from ?

Comment: Could he simply be referring to all of the rehabilitation processes in Torah? Gehinom, for example, "returns us" to Hashem "by force"

Comment: @RabbiKaii possibly...

Comment: The Meiri (חבור התשובה, מאמר א) discusses repentance born of suffering (exemplified in Yirm'yahu 31:17-18) rather than from intrinsic regret for the sin. Suffering became necessary to affect the incorrigible sinner ("כעגל לא למד"). Because the penitent has not changed his attitude towards the enjoyment he derived from his sins nor habituated himself to control his base instincts, he may readily relapse when confronted with temptation. This category of repentance requires a follow-up process of introspection, regret, and reflection upon the wrongfulness of the previous wayward behavior.